# HTTP 404 status not found error

Tags: spring-boot, pivotal-web-services

I am new to Spring boot application development. I have installed STS  with most updated version in Windows 7. I am using jdk8. I have Pivotal server  3.2. When I am trying to run my project on server i am getting 404 status not found error in Chrome.

I have searched in Stackoverflow and in internet and tried various configuration but still getting the error.

Could anyone help to let me understand how can I start the server ??

Comment: How are you starting your server? What URL are you trying to reach? Look at http://idownvotedbecau.se/nomcve/ for information on adding a minimum, complete, and verifiable example.

Comment: http://localhost:8080/restful-web-services1/WEB-INF/classes/com/in28minutes/rest/webservices/restfulwebservices1/HelloWorldController.java 


I am using this server

Comment: Server name :: Pivotal tc Runtime 3.2.8.RELEASE/8.5.23.A.RELEASE
Description The origin server did not find a current representation for the target resource or is not willing to disclose that one exists.